# Process XML data with Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am software written in Java which read an external XML file (let's call it "datasource.xml").
This file contains different information and this information are extracted using XPath queries.

The fact is that, according to what kind of information is extracted from that file (datasource.xml) a different work flow is needed. At the moment workflows are "hard coded" in my Java classes but I want to make my software indipedent so that it can work with any datasource.xml, no matter of its structure. But of course I have to specify somewhere how to deal with the extracted data. I was thinking to use (again) JAXB and specify inside the XML file (and from its XSD I will create JAXB classes) the kind of workflow is needed.

Could it be a good solution??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) (a project from JBoss) very easy to learn & is an excellent workflow tool.

building your own workflow engine is quite complex & there are a lot of considerations to be taken into account.

Comment: Ok, I explain better my situation: with the XPath expression I can get back a Node or a NodeList for example; according to what I get back I have to process them in a different way, display them in a different way and so on, for example. With those tools is it possible to do it?

Comment: You need to have some decision making using XML config, using JAXB will address you needs.

Comment: looks like you are trying to build your own workflow engine... with Drools the parsing of the XML document (BPNM 2.0) is done by drools, the api helps you to control the execution of the workflow... each step in the workflow corresponds to a particular class/event which can be triggered, this way you can control which activity needs to be called when..

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using [activiti](http://www.activiti.org/), Another workflow solution. It has APIs available and can be used as a workflow service layer in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I think you will be better off using a higher-level tool for this rather than hand-coding the logic in Java. Take a look at XProc (for example the Calabash implementation), or Orbeon, or Cocoon. They all have a learning curve associated with them, but once mastered, you will have a much more flexible architecture than with hard-coded Java logic.